# Production log not generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am facing issue on production environment.
Logs are not generated on `production.log` file.

tried few configuration changes on `production.rb`

**First Solution**:

`config.log_level = :info`

`RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new('log/production.log')`

**Second Solution**

`config.log_level = :info`

`config.logger = Logger.new('log/production.log')`

But both the solution is not working. And on production all the logs are redirected to the `unicorn.stdout.log`
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should inspect file permission of `log/production.log`, and you should ensure that `SyslogLogger` wasn't  in use.

Comment: @GentryChen yes I checked for `SyslogLogger`, we not used this

Comment: Rails write logs to log/production.log by default. Try to inspect Rails.logger in console (RAILS_ENV=production rails c).